# C++ program is crashing on constructor

Tags: c++, crash

I have strange crash on my program.  I run the program in a Linux environment.

This is the code:

```
class classB
{
public:
    classB(classA* pi_pCreator)
    {
        m_pCreator = pi_pCreator;
    }

    bool DoAction()
    {
        if(m_pCreator)
        {
            //do some code
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

private:
    classA* m_pCreator = NULL;
};

void Correlate(classA* pi_pCreator)
{
    classB l_oCorrelate(pi_pCreator);
    bool res = l_oCorrelate.DoAction();
    if (res)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        pi_pCreator->DoErrorAction();
    }
}
```

I am using crashfind to find the source of the crash and result is referring to this line:

> classB l_oCorrelate(pi_pCreator);

Usually the function `Correlate` is called with a valid `pi_pCreator`, but also there are some cases with NULL.

Is the constructor of `classB` is really the problem, or is dereferencing the problem?

Comment: Think about the `correlate()` function. With your current code, the only way it can enter the `else` block is if the `pi_pCreator` pointer is null.

Comment: Tip: in C++ use `nullptr` instead of C's typeless `NULL`.

Comment: Is there anywhere in your code that you delete a pointer by any chance? I tested your code and the only way I could get a crash was that when a deleted pointer was passed to Correlate function.

Comment: i agrre that the only way it will enter the else block, is when the pointer is null, but why crashfind still show the line of constructor? it just like assignment to NULL

Comment: also, this pointer is valid until exit the program, so the case is only when passing NULL. is there a chance that crashfind missed it?